# Javascript modal to work only if button was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im using HTML and have this javascript modal for a custom popup in my site.
my only issue is that the modal works if you click on the button **and** on the background.

I want the modal to work **only if the button is clicked**.
(code will return error if you click on modal A or B option as the rest of the code is unrelated.)

I have tried adding modal buttons and main button the same ids + adding the `data-backdrop="static"` but its not what im looking for.

```js
$(document).on('click','#select',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal();
});
$(document).on('click','.option',function(){
        var option_text = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text(option_text).val(option_text);
        //alert(option_text);
        document.getElementById("reason").value = option_text;
        $( "#connection_form" ).submit();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

```html
                                <button class="button button" onclick="openNav()">button</button>
                                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                                        <div id="select" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
                                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Connection Reason</h4>
                                              </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary option">B</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary option">A</button>

                                              </div>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
```

**EDIT:**
I used to have this code which didn't made an auto submit issue:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var reason = prompt("Please enter case number:");
  if (reason == null || reason == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = reason ;
  }
  var txt = reason;
  document.getElementById("myField").value = txt;
  return txt
}
function myFunction(frm) {
  var txt;
  var reason = prompt("Please  number:");
  if (reason == null || reason == "") {
    txt = "CANCEL";
  } else {
    txt = reason;
  }
  frm.reason.value = txt; // 1st option
  return txt
}
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="connection"  id="connection_form">

 <button name="thing"  value=button class="button button" onclick="myFunction(form);openNav()"> button </button>
<input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i first click the button it is auto-submitting with the new modal.
even if i tried @Arun K example with submit button. as i clicked the first button called button before modal pops up it is auto-submit.

Comment: This is not java, it is javascript only.

Comment: You said `data-backdrop="static"` doesn't do what you're looking for. But that makes it so the modal isn't dismissed when you click the background. Can you clarify what you want to happen (or not happen)?

Comment: The data-backdrop only make so that modal wouldn't disappear if i click on background, i do want it to disappear if no option A or B was clicked so user can dismiss modal popup. i just want the button to make modal popup and not clicking on the background after it has pop. you can see from the code snip that modal will pop if you click on the white background. if this is not possible and i need a "close" button ill do it i just cant solve it.. @AndroidNoobie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my auto-submit issue was turning button from :

```
<button class="button button" id="newselect">button</button>
```

to:

```
<button class="button button" id="newselect" type="button">button</button>
```

Adding `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your button is not working, because you given the event
on '#select' which is the id of 'div' not the button you are clicking

add a new id to your button element like below

```
<button class="button button" onclick="openNav()" id="newselect">button</button>
```

to work this button , add the click event like below

```
$(document).on('click','#newselect',function(){
            $("#myModal").modal({
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: false
             });
});
```

For closing the model just change the button A/B like below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary option"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

then for submitting

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary option" id="submission">Submit</button>
```

and in your code please change like below('.option' changed to '#submission')

```
$(document).on('click','#submission',function(){
        var option_text = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text(option_text).val(option_text);
        //alert(option_text);
        document.getElementById("reason").value = option_text;
        $( "#connection_form" ).submit();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');//if you dont want to hide remove this line
});
```

Comment: It works but i have a form before the button so that - you need to click the button and then get the modal and then it pass the form. now with that change it is making form work before i clicked on an option in the modal :  

`<form target="_blank" method="get" action="connection" style="display: inline;" id="connection_form">`

`$( "#connection_form" ).submit();`

Comment: i made some changes added backdrop: 'static',   keyboard: false. if not solved your issue please refer below link which may help you https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-closing-when-clicking-outside.php

Comment: The static added only that i couldn't  close modal pop up  by clicking on the background. the issue now is that for some reason is that after i click on button, it is auto submitting the form - also after i commented the `$( "#connection_form" ).submit();` in my modal. i dont know what causing the auto submit im looking into it. Thank you very much!

Comment: It will submit the form because ‘option ‘ class is applied for both A and B buttons , so make two different ids for both buttons, one for close other for submission

Comment: Any chance to give me more details ? i dont know Js so im not sure i got the "so make two different ids for both buttons, one for close other for submission" , I did change the on click `.option` to a id name and gave A and B buttons that same ID ,  behavior is the same.

Comment: Thanks i have tried it but it gives me the same result, it is always auto-submitting the form as i clicks the button. if i comment the <form> then it doesn't happens. i had a pop up before this modal that worked as a text box and it didnt do this auto submit. ill add the example in my answer edits.